# Beginner Timer Threaded Program to Answer a Riddle

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task

So I'm trying to answer a question my friend got in a job interview by writing a program to solve the question: "At the two second time mark, a mosquito starts spawning another mosquito every second at the mark and thereafter. Starting with one mosquito at t = 0s, how many mosquitoes will we have after 8.5 seconds?"

```
public class ok
    {
        public static int num;

        public static void mosquito()
        {
            Task.Delay(1000);
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.Interval = 1000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            num++;
            ThreadStart mos = mosquito;

        }
    }

public static void Main()
        {
            ok.mosquito();
            SendWithDelay();

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Prints mosquito count after 8.5 seconds
        private static async Task SendWithDelay()
        {
            await Task.Delay(8500);
            Console.WriteLine(ok.num);
        }
```

This is the simple code I tried to write, but obviously failed miserably. I tried reading the Task API and understanding what's going on in a better way, and I'm aware I need to make sure that access to the variable "num", which keeps track of the mosquito count is thread safe, but I'm quite rusty on this.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide expected output and actual output.

Comment: Why d you think you need Threads and Timers?  First ask yourself if you want to solve it or simulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turning the problem over, all mosquitos that are two seconds old spawn another mosquito, so we need a little history, lets use an array:

```
int[9] mosquitoHistory;
```

Starting with a timer makes things complex, assuming things happen once every second, lets use a loop.

```
for (i = 0, i++, i < 9)
{
```

If we can get the number of mosquitos from 2s ago

```
int matureMosquitos = (seconds-2 >= 0 ? mosquitoHistory[seconds-2] : 0);
```

Write the number of mosquitos for this second, i.e. how many we has last second plus the number the mature ones spawned.

```
mosquitoHistory[seconds] = (seconds-1 >= 0 ? mosquitoHistory[seconds-1] : 1) + matureMosquitos;
```

And output the result

```
Console.WriteLine(mosquitoHistory[seconds]);
```

Finally if you want it to simulate just sleep a second:

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Put it all together and this is what you get.

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] mosquitoHistory = new int[9];
        for (int seconds = 0; seconds < 9; seconds++)
        {
            int matureMosquitos = (seconds-2 >= 0 ? mosquitoHistory[seconds-2] : 0);
            mosquitoHistory[seconds] = (seconds-1 >= 0 ? mosquitoHistory[seconds-1] : 1) + matureMosquitos;                 
            Console.WriteLine(mosquitoHistory[seconds]); 
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

and I get 34 mosquitos.

Comment: And I've only just realised it outputs the Fibonacci Sequence.

Comment: this is the correct answer as there will be 13 fully mature mosq, 13 newly born mosq with 2 secs of maturity left, and finally 8 mosq with one second of maturity left which totals 34, good answer

Answer (score -1):

Its a simple descrete `2^n` algorithm.

```
2s mark we have 1 + 1 = 2
3s mark we have 1 + 1 + 2 = 4
4s mark we have 1 + 1 + 2 + 4 = 8
5s mark we have 1 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 = 16
```

etc.

Code sample

```
var numMosqito = 1;
for (float time = 0; time  <= 8.5; time ++)
{
     if (time  >= 2)
         numMosqito += numMosqito;


     Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", time, numMosqito);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: well you could've just used the Math.Pow(2,n-1)

Comment: I think each mosquito takes 2 seconds to mature before it starts spawning new mosquitos.

Comment: this isn't correct as for each mosq spawned they have to wait 2 more secs to spawn so it doesn't just double every second